# Is it possible to use custom properties as driver to control an action?

Tags: animation, drivers

Looks like with **Action Constrain**, only transform attributes can drive actions. Is it possible to use custom properties to do this?

[image]

Comment: By driving  the transform of the target object with a custom prop?

Comment: @batFINGER That'll work, but I want more clean way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable **Evaluation Time** check box. Then drive the value from any custom property. In this case you do not need to specify any target object.

Comment: finally, a perfect way, thanks